# How env('APP_DEBUG',1) and Log::debug will impact the performance in Lumen/Laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm building applications using Lumen & Laravel and I use env and Log::debug in many many places

Now when I push my applications to production will env and Log::debug gonna impact the performance?

Should I go and replace them in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use the `env()` helper anywhere except in your config files. It should only be a way of filling config files with env variables. This is mainly due to configuration caching, you can read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching.

So instead of `env('APP_DEBUG',1)`, which will always return `1` if you have a config cache, you should use `config('app.debug',1)`.

Now, talking about your performances concerns, putting something into the logs has a cost. Honnestly i just didn't know so i did a simple test on my currently opened vagrant box.

`for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){ Log::debug("helloworld"); };` => 7.7 seconds

`for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){};` => 0.0007 seconds

That's said, in a real use case, you rarely make that kind of loop and the benefits of adding logs is worth it. Adding a Log has a cost of 0.00007 s per iteration here, not much actually.

Accessing the config howerer is pretty much costless as the same test, for 100 000 iterations, takes 0.1713 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's log basically does file write operations or maybe 3rd party calls to system like slack for log notifications. It depends on what drivers you have setup for which log level. [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#configuration)

- Having `Log:debug()` to log custom messages/debug traces on live will not impact much for considerable number of requests but if it's on every page's header/footer and you have 1000 calls per second, I would say you are adding extra logging operations for each request.
- But is also depends on what you are logging. If its a string msg then
  its fine but you are logging a large collection object then I would
  say it will impact a little on the request's response time.
- Secondly, `APP_DEBUG` is a flag used by some packages to additionally calculate and provide you information helpful during development. For example package like [`barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). If you have such packages enabled on production with `APP_DEBUG=true`, this is going to pretty much consume some extra memory.
- `APP_DEBUG` also dumps your errors with stack-trace of exception. On production you would want to hide that information and just show standard error page. So I will encourage you to disable APP_DEBUG=false on live.